# iPad layer shadow effect for UIView

Tags: ipad, uiview, uiviewanimationtransition

I am trying to display a UIView similar to this image url

[Click here to view uiview image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/192/screenshot20110615at102.png/)

This is a UIView containing UIimageview and label.
Is there a way to set layer effect similar to this?

Thanks in advance
Joe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

you can use

```
imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0;
imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
imageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
imageView.layer.shadowPath = [self createArcShadowPathForRect:imageView.frame].CGPath

#define archeight 25

-(UIBezierPath *)createArcShadowPathForRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGFloat h_padding =  (self.imageView.frame.size.width - rect.size.width) /2;
    CGFloat v_padding =  (self.imageView.frame.size.height - rect.size.height) /2-10;

    CGPoint startPoint =        CGPointMake(0 + h_padding, rect.size.height + v_padding) ;
    CGPoint pointTwo =          CGPointMake(0 + h_padding, rect.size.height + archeight + v_padding) ;
    CGPoint controlCenterPoint =   CGPointMake(rect.size.width/2 + h_padding, rect.size.height + v_padding+ 10);
    CGPoint leftDownPoint =     CGPointMake(rect.size.width + h_padding, rect.size.height + archeight + v_padding) ;
    CGPoint leftUpPoint =       CGPointMake(rect.size.width + h_padding, rect.size.height + v_padding) ;

    UIBezierPath *path = nil;
    if(!path) {
        path = [[UIBezierPath bezierPath] retain];
        [path moveToPoint:startPoint];
        [path moveToPoint:pointTwo];        
        [path addQuadCurveToPoint:leftDownPoint controlPoint:controlCenterPoint];
        [path addLineToPoint:leftUpPoint];
        [path addLineToPoint:startPoint];
        [path closePath];

    }
    return path;
}
```